# BizTalk Mapping - xslt muenchian grouping and sum with case

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

The Situation here is Input having a field "Type" , "StateCode" and "amount"  in each detail , the output sample have Detail and StateDetail . All the Detail from Input needs to map to detail (one-one) but the StateDetail should group based on state and type(1 or 2 )  and  sum all the amount for each state ( the Output Sample will explain it )

Input XML :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://TestConvoys.Input2">
  <Record>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
          <Name>Danny</Name>
          <Addr>Overland</Addr>
      <State>KS</State>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
          <Name>Larry</Name>
          <Addr>Overland</Addr>
      <State>KS</State>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
          <Name>Sam</Name>
          <Addr>Miami</Addr>
      <State>FL</State>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
          <Name>Ricky</Name>
          <Addr>Kansas</Addr>
      <State>FL</State>
          <Amount>200</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
          <Name>kenny</Name>
          <Addr>Newjersey</Addr>
      <State>CA</State>
          <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
          <Name>John</Name>
          <Addr>Overland</Addr>
      <State>CA</State>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
          <Name>Bailey</Name>
          <Addr>Overland</Addr>
      <State>TX</State>
          <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
          <Name>Sam</Name>
          <Addr>Miami</Addr>
      <State>TX</State>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
          <Name>Ricky</Name>
          <Addr>Kansas</Addr>
      <State>KS</State>
          <Amount>200</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
          <Name>kenny</Name>
          <Addr>Newjersey</Addr>
      <State>KS</State>
          <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Detail>
  </Record>
</ns0:Root>
```

Expected Output :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://TestConvoys.Output">
  <Record>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Danny</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>Larry</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Sam</Name>
      <Address>Miami</Address>
      <StateCode>FL</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>Ricky</Name>
      <Address>Kansas</Address>
      <StateCode>FL</StateCode>
      <Amount>200</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>kenny</Name>
      <Address>Newjersey</Address>
      <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
      <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Bailey</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>TX</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>Sam</Name>
      <Address>Miami</Address>
      <StateCode>TX</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Ricky</Name>
      <Address>Kansas</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>200</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>kenny</Name>
      <Address>Newjersey</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <StateDetail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>50</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>100</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>FL</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>100</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>200</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>300</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>150</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>TX</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>100</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>100</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
    </StateDetail>
  </Record>
</ns0:Root>
```

XSLT Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://TestConvoys.Input2" xmlns:ns0="http://TestConvoys.Output">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:key name="group1" match ="Detail" use ="State"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
    <ns0:Root>
      <Record>
         <xsl:for-each select="Record/Detail">
          <Detail>
            <Type>
              <xsl:value-of select="Type/text()" />
            </Type>
              <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name/text()" />
              </Name>
              <Address>
                <xsl:value-of select="Addr/text()" />
              </Address>
              <StateCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="State/text()" />
              </StateCode>
              <Amount>
                <xsl:value-of select="Amount/text()" />
              </Amount>
          </Detail>
        </xsl:for-each>

          <StateDetail>
            <xsl:for-each select="Record/Detail[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('group1',State))]">
            <xsl:sort select="State" order="ascending"/>
            <Detail>
            <StateCode>
              <xsl:value-of select="State/text()" />
            </StateCode>
            <TotalAmountType1>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group1', State[../Type=1])/Amount)"/>
            </TotalAmountType1>
            <TotalAmountType2>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group1', State[../Type=2])/Amount)"/>
            </TotalAmountType2>
            </Detail>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </StateDetail>


      </Record>
    </ns0:Root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual XSLT OutPut :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://TestConvoys.Output">
  <Record>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Danny</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>Larry</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Sam</Name>
      <Address>Miami</Address>
      <StateCode>FL</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>Ricky</Name>
      <Address>Kansas</Address>
      <StateCode>FL</StateCode>
      <Amount>200</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>kenny</Name>
      <Address>Newjersey</Address>
      <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
      <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Bailey</Name>
      <Address>Overland</Address>
      <StateCode>TX</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>Sam</Name>
      <Address>Miami</Address>
      <StateCode>TX</StateCode>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <Name>Ricky</Name>
      <Address>Kansas</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>200</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Type>2</Type>
      <Name>kenny</Name>
      <Address>Newjersey</Address>
      <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
      <Amount>50</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <StateDetail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>150</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>0</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>FL</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>300</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>0</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>KS</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>450</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>0</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <StateCode>TX</StateCode>
        <TotalAmountType1>200</TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>0</TotalAmountType2>
      </Detail>
    </StateDetail>
  </Record>
</ns0:Root>
```

The XSLT is summing all the amount but not on the case i mentioned , dont know what i am missing

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        <TotalAmountType1>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group1', State[../Type=1])/Amount)"/>
        </TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group1', State[../Type=2])/Amount)"/>
        </TotalAmountType2>
```

do:

```
        <TotalAmountType1>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group1', State)[Type=1]/Amount)"/>
        </TotalAmountType1>
        <TotalAmountType2>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('group1', State)[Type=2]/Amount)"/>
        </TotalAmountType2>
```